# Want to display a chart using a query on my laravel php setup

Tags: php, laravel

So I need to show a pie chart, and I want to use this query

SELECT employees.id,employees.first_name, (SELECT SUM(training_hours.Hours) TotalTrainingHours) as TotalTrainingHours,
(employees.TrainingHoursRequired - (SELECT SUM(training_hours.Hours) TotalTrainingHours)) as TrainingHoursRemaining
FROM employees
INNER JOIN training_hours on training_hours.employee_id = employees.id

however on laravel it shows this error

Call to undefined method `Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::innerJoin()`

on my website controller for the query function i am using this code

```
function index()
    {
        $result=DB::table("employees")
        ->innerJoin("training_hours", function($join){
            $join->on("training_hours.employee_id", "=", "employees.id");
        })
        ->select("employees.id", "employees.first_name", "(select sum(training_hours.hours) totaltraininghours) as totaltraininghours", "(employees.traininghoursrequired - (select sum(training_hours.hours) totaltraininghours)) as traininghoursremaining")
        ->get();
        dd($result);
```

What should I do here?

I am using a google visualization pie chart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no innerJoin inside the `Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder` that's why you're getting an undefined `innerJoin()`, try using `join`. You can check laravel Documentation how they use innerJoin query [here](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#joins)

```
$result=DB::table("employees")
    ->join("training_hours", 'training_hours.employee_id', '=', 'employees.id')
    ->select("employees.id", "employees.first_name", "(select sum(training_hours.hours) totaltraininghours) as totaltraininghours", "(employees.traininghoursrequired - (select sum(training_hours.hours) totaltraininghours)) as traininghoursremaining")
    ->get();
```

Comment: I tried it, but im getting a different error now.
Illuminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054

Comment: what column? meaning there's a column in the query that doesn't exist in your database table, try checking your query and each column.